# When is it safe to delete an EBS volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a bunch of EBS volumes that appear to be unused, but I'm not sure how to confirm it's safe to delete them.

- Is a volume having `State: "available"` and `Attachments: []` (empty list) synonymous?
- Are AMIs or EC2 snapshots ever stored as EBS volumes?

  - Generally speaking, does AWS use volumes for anything besides attaching them to EC2 instances?

Comment: Available, no attachment means it isn't attached to any EC2 server. I'm not sure what you mean by EC2 snapshots "using" EBS volumes. That's not true. An EC2 snapshot is just a snapshot/backup of an EBS volume. The snapshot would have no reason to exist if it depended on the EBS volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is a very broad question in the sense that the term "safe" can be very loosely defined. In general, I would say if your volume is not attached to an instance, and you have a recent snapshot of the volume, then it should be safe to delete.

Comment: Are volumes ever used as storage for snapshots, AMIs, or anything else that might make me want to hold onto the volume?

Comment: I am not aware of any other AWS features at this time, besides EC2, that utilize EBS volumes. AMI volumes are created from snapshots of EBS volumes http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a snapshot and you don't have an instance attached to the volume, you can safely remove the volumes. Volumes can be recreated from snapshots.

Here is a good explanation:

[https://help.skeddly.com/en/articles/1295444-the-difference-between-ebs-snapshots-and-ami-images#:~:text=An%20EBS%20snapshot%20is%20a%20backup%20of%20a%20single%20EBS%20volume.&text=An%20AMI%20image%20is%20a,the%20AMI%20image%20was%20created](https://help.skeddly.com/en/articles/1295444-the-difference-between-ebs-snapshots-and-ami-images#:%7E:text=An%20EBS%20snapshot%20is%20a%20backup%20of%20a%20single%20EBS%20volume.&text=An%20AMI%20image%20is%20a,the%20AMI%20image%20was%20created).